# Как использовать эту функцию?

Tags: kernel, c, linux

find_task_by_name

Как ее использовать? В гугле искал, но так нормально ничего не нашел... вернее нашел, но там выдает ошибку

> `error: implicit declaration of function ‘find_task_by_name’`

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка говорит о том, что в программе отсутствует определение прототипа функции, 
и компилятор делает собственные предположения о том, какие аргументы она принимает, и какие результаты возвращает.

1) Найти правильный заголовочный файл, в котором определен прототип этой функции

```
find / -name "*.h" | xargs grep find_task_by_name
```

2) Понять, какая библиотека должна быть подключена к программе для использования этой функции

3) Собрать программу с использованием нужной библиотеки

Comment: это все должно долго искаться? а то минут 5 ищет и курсор в терминале просто мигает и все(

Comment: в 2 или 4 потока можно искать эту библиотеку?

Comment: ничего не нашлось, это значит что этой библиотеки нет? если ее нет, то как установить ее?

Comment: искать по всему диску... это конечно сильно.

Comment: Это ядерная функция, у них свои хедеры и вообще все особое.

Comment: А учитывая то, что это функция скорее термоядерная (т.е. в хедерах ядра её нет), то find'ом комп можно долго тренировать.

Comment: Ужас! `man git grep`

Answer (score 1):

А откуда Вы это чудо взяли? Мне стало интересно, спросил гугла, и он (под большим секретом) дал ссылку на [статью в opennet](http://www.opennet.ru/base/dev/proccess_in_linux.txt.html). Только вот там это функция самописная (приведён текст). А нужные прототипы лежат в linux/sched.h (у меня это
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-33/include/linux/sched.h пакет linux-headers-2.6.32-33).

Answer (score 0):

[Здесь](http://www.deltann.ru/10/d-112007/p-131) не смотрели?

Comment: да вот как раз там и смотрел(((

Comment: Так в этой статье ее код и приведен. Скопируйте к себе и вызывайте.